# Problema al Instanciar App() o AppFactory()

Tags: php, slim, phpstorm

Quiero ejecutar el siguiente codigo en php usando el framework slim 4.2

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiate App
$app = AppFactory::create();

// Add error middleware
$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

// Add route
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response       $response, $args) {
$name = $args['name'];
$response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");
return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Could not detect any PSR-17 ResponseFactory implementations. Please install a supported implementation in order to use `AppFactory::create().

Me sale ese error, ya intente ejecutar distintas variariones de un simple codigo, pero me sigue saliendo este tipo de errores. No encuentro en la documentacion informacion relacionada con este tipo de problemas.

***Contenido de composer.json***

```
 {
"require": {
    "slim/slim": "^4.2",
    "slim/http": "^0.7.0"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te estaría faltando agregar `PSR-7`.

### Solución:

Según [la documentación](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim#hello-world-using-appfactory-with-psr-7-auto-detection)

> Para que la detección automática funcione y le permita usar `AppFactory::create()` y `App::run()` sin tener que crear manualmente un `ServerRequest`, necesita instalar una de las siguientes implementaciones:
>
> - **Slim-Psr7** - Install using `composer require slim/psr7`
> - **Nyholm/psr7 & Nyholm/psr7-server** - Install using `composer require nyholm/psr7 nyholm/psr7-server`
> - **Guzzle/psr7 & http-interop/http-factory-guzzle** - Install using `composer require guzzlehttp/psr7 http-interop/http-factory-guzzle`
> - **zend-diactoros** - Install using `composer require zendframework/zend-diactoros`

---

Referencias:

- [Slim Framework 4.x > Choose a PSR-7 Implementation & ServerRequest Creator](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/4.x/README.md#choose-a-psr-7-implementation--serverrequest-creator)

Comment: Este error me sale ahora, el anterior se solucionó:Slim Application Error:
Type: Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException
Code: 404
Message: Not found.